# I have a comma being added to one parameter in my multipart form in Angular

Tags: angular, http, post

I have a multipart form I am sending in a post request in Angular 13. All of the parameters are going through correctly except one, that has a comma added to the beginning of the string in the value of the param.

I have logged the form using FormData.entries() at the point of the form being added to the post request API call and the comma is not there. Checking the logs in Java however, the comma is added, but only to the one parameter.

simplified version of ts file:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
product: [""],
id: [""],
category: [""],
...
...
})
...
submitForm(){
let f = this.form.value
let formData = new FormData()
for(let value in f){
if(value === "id"){
formData.append("adjId, f[value])
} else {
formData.append(value, f[value])
}
this.httpService.submitForm(formData).subscribe((data:any)=> {
if(data.success)...
}
...
checkIfIdisValid(e:any){
let form = {
id: event.name
}
console.log(form)
this.httpService.checkIfIdIsValid(form).subscribe((data:any)=> {
if(data.success){
...}
}
```

http service:

```
submitForm(formData:any):Observable<any>{
for(let pair of formData.entries()){
console.log("Form Params:", pair[0]+': '+ pair[1])
}
return this.http.post("url, formData)
}
```

html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
...
<custom-dropdown formControlName="id" (change)="checkIfIdisValid($event)" valueField="name" [valuePrimitive]="true">
...
</form>
```

The custom dropdown event logs the value without the comma, but the data also fails on that API call. Java shows the data coming as null. The other API call shows it with a leading comma even though both console.log() functions show the correct data without commas.

Comment: Is this: `formData.append("adjId, f[value])` the problem? Are you missing a `"` in there somewhere? Your code in the post is a mess. Hard to help you when this is what you post.

Comment: Sorry, the " is in the original code. I don't have access to post the original code here, so I just free hand wrote it out real quick. I'll try to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating the formControlName to match the value instead of using an if condition to update the name.

Before you ask, there were some other variables associated with the other name, I just created a workaround to use the other formControlName. Still no clue why it was adding a comma, but at least it works now.